# R- Apply a function with a range of variables in an argument

Tags: r, function, range

I want to use a function, that requires a variable for one argument, using a range of values for that argument. Ideally I'd like to store all the resulting values from the function in a list.

I have tried making a loop and assigning it to a function that passes the range of values to the function, but it is not working. As you can guess, my experience with R is very small.

```
MyfuncRange <- function(t_range, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6){
  for (t in t_range)
Myfunc(t, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6)
}
```

I have tried looking for a way to do this, but I could only find ways to apply the same function for a range of data.

Comment: Could you please provide a reproducible example of your data? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Basically, what I want is to use function `Myfunc` with the same values for var2-var6 but changing the value for var1, using values from a range of values.

Comment: How exactly it is not working? Does it return an error? Did you try a ply formula like sapply for the range of values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
sapply(t_range, Myfunc, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That works perfectly for using the same function! Thanks!
However, I also wanted to add the results to a data.frame
I could do it using:

`MyfuncRange <- function(t_range, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6){

  result <- data.frame()

  for (t in t_range){

    tmp <- Myfunc(t_range, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6)

    result <- rbind(result, data.frame(t,tmp))}
  
  return(result)
}`

Is there a way of doing this using sapply?

Comment: @eggrandio Maybe you could try this:    data.frame(t(rbind(t_range, sapply(t_range, Myfunc, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6))))

Comment: Thank you @Consistency ! that worked perfectly, and takes less time than the for loop I had created!